# Spin Up Docker Mongo With Replica Set

Tags: c#, mongodb, docker

For automation tests, both locally and on build servers, I'm trying to spin up a mongo image with a replica set (I need the oplog).

The replica set setup requires me to get into the mongo shell and call "*rs.initiate()*". I want this all done in code.

```
public void SpinUpMongoWithReplicaSet()
{
    Process.Start("docker", "run -p 123:27017 --name test_mongo -d mongo:latest mongod --replSet rs0").WaitForExit();

    var replicaSetProcess = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "docker",
            Arguments = "exec -it test_mongo mongo",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardInput = true
        }
    };

    replicaSetProcess.Start();

    using(StreamWriter writer = replicaSetProcess.StandardInput)
    {
        writer.WriteLine("rs.initiate()");
        writer.WriteLine("exit");
    }

    replicaSetProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

However, the problem with the docker exec command.

When passing in **-it** or just **-t**, I get the following error:

> the input device is not a TTY.  If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'

The only solution I could find is to only pass in the **-i** flag. For whatever reason, this then prevents me from connecting to the mongo container:

> MongoDB shell version v3.4.9
>   connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
>   2017-10-06T18:25:06.765+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
>   2017-10-06T18:25:06.765+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
>   connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
>   @(connect):1:6
>   exception: connect failed

Does anyone have any experience in executing commands on docker images within C# code?

---

For reference: this is a good guide to setting up a mongo replica set server with docker, but from the command line.
[Docker Replica Set Setup](http://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2016/06/30/docker-mongo-replica-set/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Mongo has a way of evaluating text using the **--eval** flag.

This allows us to avoid using both **-i** and **-t** flags. In this manner, the **Process.Start()** function will be sufficient.

Solution:

```
Process.Start("docker", "exec test_mongo mongo --eval \"rs.initiate()\"").WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.42/#tag/Container/operation/ContainerCreate endpoint with Docker.DotNet.Models class, you can create the container replica set with the following lines:

```
var config = new Config()
            {
                Cmd = new List<string>(){"--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all"},
                Healthcheck = new HealthConfig
                {
                    Test = new List<string>(){"CMD-SHELL","mongosh --eval \"rs.initiate()\""},
                    StartPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2).Ticks,
                },
            };
```